# How to write a complex Mysql Query in Django

Tags: python, mysql, django

I am new to Django and I am working on a small module of a Django application where I need to display the list of people who have common interest as that of any particular User. So Suppose if I am an user I can see the list of people who have similar interests like me.

For this I have 2 models :

**models.py**

```
class Entity(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class UserLikes(models.Model):
    class Meta:
       unique_together = (('user', 'entity'),)

    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    entity = models.ForeignKey(Entity)

    def __str__(self):
    return self.user.username + " : " + self.entity.name
```

So in the Entity Table I store the Entities in which user can be interested *Eg : football, Music, Code etc.*

and in the `UserLikes` I store the relation about which user likes which entity.

Now I have a Query to fetch details about which user has maximum interest like any particular user  :

```
SELECT y.user_id, GROUP_CONCAT(y.entity_id) likes, COUNT(*) total
FROM likes_userlikes x
JOIN likes_userlikes y ON y.entity_id = x.entity_id AND y.user_id <> x.user_id
WHERE x.user_id = ?
GROUP BY y.user_id
ORDER BY total desc;
```

Problem is how do I write this Query using Django Querysets and change it into a function.

Comment: use `raw`? UserLikes.objects.raw('...')

Answer (score 2):

```
# this gives you what are current user's interests
current_user_likes = UserLikes.objects.filter(user__id=user_id) \
                                      .values_list('entity', flat=True).distinct()
# this gives you who are the persons that shares the same interests
user_similar_interests = UserLikes.objects.filter(entity__id__in=current_user_likes) \
                                          .exclude(user__id=user_id) \
                                          .values('user', 'entity').distinct()
# finally the count
user_similar_interests_count = user_similar_interests.count()
```

Here the `user_id` is the user's id you want to query for.

One advice though, it's not good practice to use plural form for model names, just use `UserLike` or better, `UserInterest` for it. Django would add plural form when it needs to.